# the measurement matrix 's jacobi to velocity should be zero ?

Tags: computer-vision, kalman-filter

as the state is [x v] , x is current state , and v is the state velocity ,

in transition matrix x(k) = x(k-1) + v(k-1)

but in the update step , the observe has no relationship with velocity ,like 
observe = f(x, something else) , f is observe function , so my question is 
the measurement jacobi matrix should have ∂f/∂v , should it to be zero , or 
∂f/∂v = ∂f(x+v)/∂(v) ?

Comment: if ∂f/∂v is zeros , the gain of v is zero,  so in the update step , the velocity is have no change , I think it's not correct

Comment: You should use 0 for df/fv. The velocity will still change in the update step because it is correlated with the position -- your state covariance matrix will not be diagonal

Comment: thank you I have make it work now :)